# 3D models for UI

Tags: website-design, resources, 3d

How can we create 3D models for a website as shown below?

https://dribbble.com/shots/3833466-Unlimited-Pass/attachments/867731

Should we use any high-end software like 3D Max or Is there any small software available?

The low poly 3d models and other models are becoming a trend these days.

Comment: This question is more related to graphic design than user experience.

Comment: You can use HTML5 Canvas. However, I'm voting to close this question as it concerns implementation, not design.

Answer (score 2):

Blender is a free open source 3D modeling tool which works great for making low poly 3d models. [Check their website](https://www.blender.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Blender is fantastic. But for quick lo-fi 3D, I like Google SketchUp. It is another quick-to-learn and free modeling program with a large library of previously uploaded models to start from. The premium upgrade may be worth the price for all the lighting FX you get.

https://www.sketchup.com/

https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/